# How does Milla's blaster get re-charged?

Tags: david-weber, apocalypse-troll

We see in one of the chapters that it is super energy intensive (taking an output of an entire Russian nuclear power plant) to charge her flight suit.

However, her blaster (able to melt and destroy Troll medium mechs and chassis) clearly requires a lot of energy, and she expended a lot of it on demonstrations to various people/governments.

How does she re-charge the blaster?

Answer (score 2):

The (magazine-fed) blaster appears to have quite a high capacity, offering eleven-ish shots at full power or over fifty shots at standard power. Also there are extra mags stored in the holster, giving our hero the ability to fire, potentially, hundreds of rounds before running out of ammo.

> “Cert. It’s wasteful, though. **At full power, I’d empty the magazine
> with twelve pulses.”**
>
> “What the hell is that thing?” he demanded. “What d’you call it?”
>
> “I’m afraid we call it a ‘blaster,’ ” she said apologetically, and he
> closed his eyes. He should have known, he told himself. “As for what
> it is, that’s a bit hard to explain—inevitably.” She met his
> long-suffering gaze understandingly. “Think of it this way, Dick: it’s
> a capacitor-fed energy weapon which projects a pulse of plasma at the
> target. **On full auto at full power, it delivers approximately
> one-point-eight k-tons of energy per second, or just over twenty-one
> and a half kilotons for the magazine, since it cycles at a pulse a
> second.** Of course,” she added thoughtfully, “if you pump the full mag
> that fast, you’ll burn out every time.”
>
> “Jesus!” he said, remembering **the extra magazines in the back of the
> holster.** “You’re a walking tactical nuke! Isn’t that a mite
> excessive?”

I don't see any indication that the magazines can be user-recharged, noting that an empty mag is treated as lost.

> Aston had begrudged the time Ludmilla had been forced to spend telling her story firsthand so many times, but in the event it had been worthwhile. **She’d used up the full charge of one blaster magazine demonstrating it to prime ministers, premiers, and generals on three continents, but it had put any doubts to rest.**

Comment: Is 11 in your first sentence a typo?

Comment: @DavidW - 21.5Kt (for the mag) divided by 1.8kt = 11

Comment: No, 12x1.8 = 21.6, which is "just over 21.5"; if it were 11, it would be 11x1.8 = 19.8 which is "just under 20."  Besides, "I’d empty the magazine with twelve pulses." is pretty clear to me, it's 12, not 11.

Comment: @DavidW - I came up with 11 **.9** and since you can't have 90% of a shot *at full power*, I assumed it was eleven and rounded down. I've edited to reflect that it's an approximation though.